# Tentando gerar um gráfico de uma série temporal

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Isso foi o que fiz..

```
#Lê a base de dados
ano1<-read.csv("os dados abaixo...",header = TRUE ,sep=";", row.names=1)

#Cria a série temporal
ano<-ts(ano1[,1],start=c(2009,1), end=c(2010,12),freq=12)

#plota a série
plot(ano,ylab='indice', xlab='ano',main='distribuiçao dos casos')
```

​Esses são os dados:​

```
​##       Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
## 2009  1.6  1.0  0.2  0.0 -0.2  0.1  0.9  1.4  0.8 -0.4 -0.8  0.1
## 2010  1.8  1.2  0.3 -0.1 -0.2 -0.3  1.5  1.9  1.2  0.1 -0.6 -0.5
```

Porém ele plota um gráfico "periódico".

​Ps.: São vários anos, mas queria aprender nesse 'simples' pra aplicar no outro.
​

Answer (score 2):

Minha sugestão seria para você transpor os dados usando o comando t() e, em seguida plotar utilizando o comando matplot() ou ts.plot().

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer usar um for para criar a lista de anos, se os dados tiver em um array, o mesmo sera populado de acordo com o indice

Segue um codigo que fiz em java seguindo um loop

```
graphDonut = Morris.Donut({
                element: 'hero-donut', // elemento chave de referencia
                data: [// dados do grafico
        <c:forEach items="${valorList}" var="catP">

                    {label: '${catP.categoria}', value: '${catP.porcentagem}'},
        </c:forEach>
                ],
                colors: ['#8bc34a', '#ffc107', '#34495e', '#03a9f4', '#9c27b0', '#90a4ae'], //cores do grafico

                formatter: function (y) {

                    return y;
                }
                , //formatação dos números a exibir
                resize: true // redimensionavel true
            });
```

Nele, temos um graphDonut, onde temos categorias e porcentagem, o forEach faz o add das categorias e porcentagem de acordo com um array que fiz no backend. abaixo a estrutura que se repete

```
{label: '${catP.categoria}', value: '${catP.porcentagem}'},
```

Se precisa de algum codigo de referencia em back, pode falar ae. Mesmo que nao esteja usando java vc pode implementar isso com algumas alterações de acordo com a linguagem